# How to pass credentials of git to bitnami airflow helm

Tags: airflow, bitnami

I am using bitnami/airflow helm chart for my kubernetes environment. I would like to pull in the dag and plugin folders from my bitbucket git repository. How can I pass cert or credentials for my git to the image

https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/bitnami/airflow

Without passing any credentials it gives my `cannot read password error`
I use this to set my git repo
airflow.clonePluginsFromGit.repository

Answer (score 0):

They mention the following in their github repo

> If you use a private repository from GitHub, a possible option to
> clone the files is using a Personal Access Token and using it as part
> of the URL:
> https://USERNAME:PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY

This should work for bitbucket too, just replace personal_access_token with one acquired from bitbucket. It might also be called an app_password depending on if you're using bitbucket cloud.

Answer (score -2):

You can configure the following parameters:

- `airflow.auth.forcePassword` to force users to specify a password
- `airflow.auth.username` is the username to access web UI
- `airflow.auth.password` is the password to access web UI
- `airflow.auth.fernetKey` to set the fernet key to secure connection
- `airflow.auth.existingSecret` is the name of an existing secret containing airflow password and fernet key

Comment: OP asks how to configure git, you answer with a list of non-git parameters.